# \def inside of \def not visible in titles or captions

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, robust-commands

The following MWE yields a compilation error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\def\AAA#1{\bgroup\def\contents{AAA}#1\egroup}
\def\BBB#1{\bgroup\def\contents{BBB}#1\egroup}

% Without this line, compilation fails
\def\contents{\relax}

\section{\AAA{\contents}}
\section{\BBB{\contents}}
\section{\AAA{\contents}}
\section{\BBB{\contents}}
\end{document}
```

> ERROR: Undefined control sequence.
>
> ```
> --- TeX said ---
> \AAA #1->\bgroup \def \contents 
>                                 {AAA}#1\egroup 
> l.12 \section{\AAA{\contents}}
> ```

However, when I uncomment the top-level `\def\contents` line, the example seems to work.

Why is this top-level `\def` needed? What are the downsides of adding it? Is there a cleaner way to do macro-local definitions (definitions that are only active in the body of the macro)?

The same issue happens with the following:

```
\begin{figure}
   \caption{\AAA{\contents}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Did you try `\gdef`? (But what is the point of the extra group?) I also don't really understand your last questions. How local do you need it to be? The same thing would happen if you defined a command inside (say) the `center` environment.

Comment: I did, but ideally I'd like the definition of `\contents` to not leak.

Comment: Well, you can `\let\contents\relax` or use something like `etoolbox`'s `\undef` (or `\csundef`). But whether this is really a good idea is unclear from this example. What's the concern with the leak?

Comment: @jon `gdef` doesn't actually work; the leak was a secondary concern.  It does work with a `section`, but it doesn't with a `\caption`, for example.

Comment: Hmm, well, I wonder if this example is too minimal. I'm still unclear as to why you are trying to bury (but then partially disinter) the command in an extra group. (Also what do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? You get an error or it isn't doing what you want it to do?)

Comment: I get an error; the same as the one I listed.  You can ignore the group; the error is the same with or without it.

Comment: `\def\AAA#1{\gdef\contents{AAA}#1}` or `\gdef\AAA#1{\def\contents{AAA}#1}`? One of these will fail.

Comment: I was using the first one.

Comment: I can make it fail if I add something like `\tableofcontents` to the file. but `\def\AAA#1{\bgroup\gdef\contents{AAA}#1\egroup}` does not cause an error in the above file, even if I add the bit about the `\caption`....

Comment: Reading your comment below makes me wonder what is `\AAA{\contents}` doing that `\AAA` can't do itself? or `\@namedef` + `\@nameuse` (though `etoolbox` has more user-friendly versions)? or something like `\def\theAAA#1{\def\AAA{#1}}`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Section and caption titles are moving arguments. They go to the `.aux` file and from there to the `.toc` or `.lof`/`.lot` file. Section titles also can appear in header lines.

When macros are written to a file, they are expanded and Werner's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336939/16967) shows this quite comprehensive. Assignments or definitions in a macro usually leads to fragile macros, they break when expanded, from Werner's answer:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}\bgroup \def {AAA}\egroup }{1}}
```

This is an invalid definition, because it tries to define `{`.

Or with `\def\contents{\relax}`:

```
\bgroup \def \relax {AAA}\relax \egroup
```

Then `\relax` is redefined, which should never be done.

A better top level definition for `\contents` is:

```
\let\contents\relax
```

Package `calc` uses the unexpandable `\ignorespaces` for this purpose:

```
\let\widthof\ignorespaces
\let\heightof\ignorespaces
\let\depthof\ignorespaces
\let\totalheightof\ignorespaces
```

Then `\contents` is *not* expanded, when written to a file:

```
\bgroup \def \contents {AAA}\contents \egroup
```

Also the definitions `\AAA` can be protected to avoid that the full definition text is written:

```
\let\contents\relax
\section{\protect\AAA{\contents}}
```

Then the `.aux` file contains:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}\AAA {\contents }}{1}}
```

and the `.toc` file:

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}\AAA {\contents }}{1}
```

Alternatively, macro `\AAA` can be made robust:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\AAA}{...}% The LaTeX2e way
\let\contents\relax
...
\section{\AAA{\contents}}
```

`.aux` file entry:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}\AAA  {\contents }}{1}}
```

Or eTeX's `\protected` can be used:

```
\protected\def\AAA#1{...}
\let\contents\relax
...
\section{\AAA{\contents}}
```

Neither `\def` nor `\DeclareRobustCommand` checks, if the macro to be defined is already defined. A dummy `\newcommand` helps to get an error message, if this is the case:

```
\newcommand{\AAA}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\AAA}[1]{...}
```

or
    \newcommand{\AAA}{}
    \protected\def\AAA#1{...}

LaTeX's interpretation of undefined macros include commands with meaning `\relax`. Therefore, `\contents` would be overwritten without error:

```
\let\contents\relax
\newcommand*{\contents}{foobar}
```

And macros `\AAA`, `\BBB` with arguments containing `\contents` inside moving arguments would be broken again. Package `calc` avoids this with the meaning `\ignorespaces` instead.

**Summary:**

```
\newcommand{\contents}{}% Check that \contents is undefined
\let\contents\ignorespaces

\newcommand{\AAA}{}%
% \DeclareRobustCommand*{\AAA}[1]{...}
\protected\def\AAA#1{\bgroup\def\contents{AAA}#1\group}

% ...
\section{\AAA{\contents}}
% ...
\caption{\AAA{\contents}}
```

Answer (score 9):

Whether you want to or not, sectional units write their arguments to the `.aux` in case you may want to use `\tableofcontents` (say). The same would hold for `\caption` that would write content to the `.aux` for when you use `\listoftables` or `\listoffigures`. For that reason, your local definition of `\contents` survives the actual setting, but not writing to the `.aux`. To get around it, you'll have to disable that feature, or supply an alternative ToC-related entry:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\AAA#1{\bgroup\def\contents{AAA}#1\egroup}
\def\BBB#1{\bgroup\def\contents{BBB}#1\egroup}

\section[AAA]{\AAA{\contents}}
\section[BBB]{\BBB{\contents}}
\section[CCC]{\AAA{\contents}}
\section[DDD]{\BBB{\contents}}

\end{document}
```

Here's what's written to the `.aux` if you don't do the above:

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}\bgroup \def {AAA}\egroup }{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}\bgroup \def {BBB}\egroup }{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}\bgroup \def {AAA}\egroup }{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4}\bgroup \def {BBB}\egroup }{1}}
```

Note how `\def` is missing its control sequence argument - `\contents` in your case - which doesn't exist at the time of writing to the `.aux`.

Even if you were to use your "fix"

```
\def\contents{\relax}
```

the expansion upon writing to the ToC would still lead to something odd:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}\bgroup \def \relax {AAA}\relax \egroup }{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}\bgroup \def \relax {BBB}\relax \egroup }{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}\bgroup \def \relax {AAA}\relax \egroup }{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4}\bgroup \def \relax {BBB}\relax \egroup }{1}}
```

Comment: Is there a generic way to work around this problem? In my case, that `\AAA` macro may end up being used in captions as well as titles, and possibly in other places.

Comment: @Clément: I guess there should be. Perhaps one can define conditionals that may be expandable and execute only the branch you need. However, I'm not sure of the entire context, and without that, I don't know how to supply a "generic work around".

Comment: Thanks.  Then context is that I have a file containing a small amount of LaTeX, and I have to macros `\AAA` and `\BBB` that implement different "styles". `\contents` appears in the file, and it is one of the things that `\AAA` and `\BBB` can change.  I'm having trouble defining `\AAA` and `\BBB` in a way that makes them usable in captions and titles.

Comment: @Clément: So, do you want `\AAA` and `\BBB` to do nothing within captions/titles, but something else when they're not in there? Or, do you want them to do something inside captions/titles, but just not cause errors when writing content to the `.aux`? As you can see, it's still not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  I was hoping to have them do the same thing in caption and titles, in the TOC, and in regular body text.  Maybe I should just scrap this approach and try using an `\ifAAA` conditional and a global protected definition of `\contents` that would check `\ifAAA`, instead of redefining `\contents` inside of `\AAA`.

Comment: @Clément: I assume `\contents` is therefore defined usually? See [this](http://pastebin.com/XMRP9VCS); perhaps using `\DeclareRobustCommand{\defcontents}{\def\contents}` would allow you to redefine `\contents` whether it's in the title or in a ToC-related entry.

Answer (score 6):

Others have explained the reason for the errors.

If you're already using `xparse`, there's a simple way out.

```
\NewDocumentCommand\contents{}{} % placeholder

\NewDocumentCommand\AAA{m}{%
  \begingroup
  \RenewDocumentCommand\contents{}{AAA}%
  #1%
  \endgroup
}
```

This is based on the fact that commands defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` are automatically robust.

You can set the default definition of `\contents` to anything you want.

You can also abstract the repeating parts:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\defcontentscommand}{mm}{%
  % #1 = macro name, #2 = tokens
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{m}{%
    \begingroup
    \RenewDocumentCommand\contents{}{#2}##1%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\contents}{}{} % placeholder
\defcontentscommand{\AAA}{AAA}
\defcontentscommand{\BBB}{BBB}
```